# Не работает WI-FI на Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, wifi

Подскажите что делать,установил Windows 8.1 и по началу все работало,пока не установились обновления.После них перестал работать вай фай,адаптер Pro/Wireless 345ABG,читал что Windows 8.1 не поддерживает данный адаптер.Как теперь быть? Удалял и устройство и драйвера и всеравно вай фай не хочет работать!

Answer (score 1):

Тут несколько вариантов.

1) Сделать откат системы.

2) Откатить сами обновления, которые были установлены за день до того, как перестал работать свисток.

Comment: Уже разобрался спасибо.Оказывается 8-ая винда вообще не поддерживает мой адаптер!